# Connecting to Insightly API using PHP and cURL

Tags: php, api, curl, insightly

I've pasted my code below.
I'm getting an empty string back, no curl error or anything.

```
$service_url = "https://api.insight.ly/v2.1/Opportunities";           
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "-my-base64-encoded-api-key");

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

since the documentation for the Insightly API said to leave password blank, i've also tried

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "-my-base64-encoded-api-key:");
```

and

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "-my-base64-encoded-api-key: ");
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: based on this: https://api.insight.ly/V2/Help/ApiController/Opportunities your url is not valid, there's more to add

Comment: Hi Dagon - this url:https://api.insight.ly/v2.1/Help/Introduction
gives the "v2.1" as the url for their service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is the working code - I had to send the authorization in the header, not as an option in CURL. I didn't know this was possible. Insightly support came through and provided me with additional instructions. I am posting the answer below in case someone else runs into this problem.

```
$service_url = 'https://api.insight.ly/v2.1/Opportunities';
$ch = curl_init($service_url);           
curl_setopt($ch, 
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
            array('Content-Type: application/json', 
                  'Authorization: Basic my-base64-encoded-api-key'));
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);           
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);           
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);            

$return = curl_exec($ch );    

curl_close($process);
```

Comment: When I try to use this code, I keep getting 404 error.

Comment: Is your API access set up properly? 404 error looks like your connection attempt is being dropped by their firewall. My guess is that maybe you have an error in the API key you are using.